# How to select every single address between specific coordinates?

Tags: sql, teradata

```
SELECT * 
FROM houses_table 
WHERE ((CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN 
           (SELECT CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) - 0.002 
            FROM houses_table  WHERE house_owner IN ('john')) 
           AND (SELECT CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) + 0.002 
                FROM houses_table  
                WHERE house_owner IN ('john'))) 
  AND (CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN
           (SELECT CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) - 0.002 
            FROM houses_table 
            WHERE house_owner IN ('john'))
       AND (SELECT CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10,6)) + 0.002 
            FROM houses_table 
            WHERE house_owner IN ('john')))
);
```

I have a database (house_owner, coordinate x, coordinate y). I want to select all the addresses where owner is john or addresses that are nearby john. I know that code is wrong because those selects returns a values in different order so it cant work. Also the definition or "nearby" should be write better but "-0.002" and "+0.002" is enough for me.

Later I added columns to my database "x min" "x max" "y min" "y max" but I don't know if that will help.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Do **not** add the rdbms tag, add the tag for the actual RDBMS you're using.

Comment: Teradata has geospatial functions to compute distances using various coordinate systems. But if you want to do it as a simple rectangle, then I assume the issue is "John" may own multiple houses? So use one subquery to compute the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax for each of John's houses and join to that, rather than multiple scalar subqueries.

Comment: This question is getting a little long in the tooth. Can you provide sample data and desired results. I believe that editing the question to include that will breathe some life back into it and get you an answer. Right now we are being asked to reverse engineer your non-working code to understand enough to solve.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I just added a better worded question